# Why didn't Einstein ever meet his daughter Lieserl?

Tags: albert-einstein

How is it possible that Albert Einstein have never met his first child with Mileva Marić? According to [Wikipedia:Einstein Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_family#Lieserl_Einstein) Lieserl was born 27 January 1902 and died around September 1903. Even if he got a lot to do - tutoring in Bern, death of his father etc. he still got nearly two years to go to Serbia to meet with Mileva and Lieserl. Does it mean that he haven't seen Mileva for over two years?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time that happened.

Comment: "Does it mean that he haven't seen Mileva for over two years?" It probably does.